# I just rebuilt the mesh for this character. Smooth shading creates odd eye shadows

Tags: shaders

I just started modeling in blender a few days ago- I did a high res model and realized that it was a bit too high poly- so I re-meshed my character and everything looked great. In flat shading, it looks great, in smooth shading, it kills my soul. I don't really know what to do to fix this.

[image: Smooth Shading][image: Flat Shading]

Comment: maybe recalculate the normals in Edit mode, or check for overlapping vertices, inner faces?

Comment: Ahhh thank you thank you @moonboots you guys fixed my issue hehe

Answer (score 3):

I think your normals are not facing the same direction as @moonboots said.

You can check them by using two buttons in the viewport overlay panel

The "Face orientations" button and the "face normals" button (at the bottom, see screen) [image: normal checking functions]

both of them will allow you to check in which direction your normals are facing.
Don't forget to set an appropriate size when you're using the "face normals" option.

You can also recompute them by going into : (when in edit mode)

Mesh -> Normal -> Recalculate outside